How to bind multiple data frames that are stored in a list with quotation marks
I am reading in the first excel sheets that each store the coded effects of one paper of a meta-analysis using R. I managed to automatically search the directory for the relevant files, open them, clean them and store them as single data frames (with names ID_1790, ID_3491, ...). In that loop I also added a dynamic vector that stores the names given to the data frames called ReadIn.
Now I want to combine the single data frames into one. This is no problem when manually generating a DataList list object and using that in a rbindlist command.
However, the number of elements in ReadIn will grow over time, and I don't want to type in each new entry in ReadIn to the DataList. There must be a way to do this automatically, but I can't find it.
> ReadIn
[1] "ID_1790" "ID_3491" "ID_6006" "ID_768"  "ID_794"  "ID_906"  "ID_956" 

> DataList <- list(ID_1790, ID_3491, ID_6006, ID_768, ID_794, ID_906, ID_956)
> MetaDat  <- rbindlist(DataList, fill=TRUE)


ReadIn: vector of Data Frame names with quotation marks - can't get rid of these, which will automatically grow, the more files are available to be read in
DataList: currently a manual list generated from the first 7 data frames. I want to get from ReadIn to DataList without having to manually update the DataList List. Instead I want to use the elements of the ReadIn vector that is dynamically created already.
MetaDat: the name of the final data set

I tried with lists, with do.call etc., but can't find a way to get this automated

I think you want mget(): mget(ReadIn) should return the equivalent of your DataList.
The help page (?mget) is rather long and technical, but it says that the first argument for mget is

a character vector of object names

and the return value is

a named list of objects (found or specified via ‘ifnotfound’).


Yes, mget did it. Thank you so much!
Code is now very simple:
DataList <- mget(ReadIn)
MetaDat  <- rbindlist(DataList, fill=TRUE)

Thanks for pointing that out. I should have read the instructions more carefully before posting my questions.

No problem .....
